# post data from ember js to python

Tags: python-2.7, ember.js, tornado

iam using ember js with python and tornado server.

I want to send the json data from ember js to python.

here is what i have tried

```
App.MyleavesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
submitAction: function () {
data=[{fromdate:this.get("model.fromdate")}]
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/apply_leave",
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  success: function ( data ) {
  }
});
}
});
```

in my python it is

```
class LeaveFormHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    print json.loads(data)
```

but i could not get data..

it says " global name 'data' is not defined"

am a newbie please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a POST request, use json.loads(self.request.body).  Arguments to post() are extracted from the url regex.

Comment: can u also tell how to get data in the server for a get type of request